# Problema com background-image acessando do navegador google chrome no celular

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, twitter-bootstrap

Estou tendo problema com minha imagem de fundo na minha página mas apenas acessando do celular pelo Chrome ou navegador padrão do celular, no Mozilla Firefox do celular funciona perfeitamente.

```
body{
    background-image: url('/assets/img/background.jpg');
    background-position: top center;
    background-repeat:  no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size:  cover;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
}
```

Podem acessar minha página aqui para conferir https://anacvignola.github.io/

e o código completo aqui https://github.com/anacvignola/anacvignola.github.io

Comment: Descreva o problema na pergunta, e não num link externo.. Facilita a visualização do problema por parte de quem quer ajudar e evita problemas, caso por exemplo os links venham a ser removidos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ana muito provavelmente seu problema é por vc não colocou uma altura com valor no `body` e no `html`

Tente colocar dessa forma que deve funcionar nos outros Browsers.

**OBS:** deixei uns comentários no código.

```
html {
    height: 100%; /* coloque uma altura no html também */
}

body{
    background-image: url('/assets/img/background.jpg');
    background-position: top center;
    background-repeat:  no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size:  cover;
    max-width: 100%;
    /* width: auto; romava esse width */
    /* height: auto; não use "auto" coloque um valor de100% ou 100vh */
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
}
```

Aqui tem um teste simples para vc fazer. Em etapas, tire o `height` do `HTML`, depois troque o `height` do `body` de **auto** para **100%** e vc vai ver como eles se comportam.

```css
html {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%; /* se vc não colocar aqui 100% o body fica sem altura e não pega a cor */
}
body {
  background-color: blue;
  height: auto; /* tire "auto" e coloque 100% para o body pegar a cor; */
  
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigada, resolveu perfeitamente (: